# Is it possible to dynamically create a MS Word "SmartArt Basic Venn" and return it to a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MS Word has a collection of "SmartArt" tools. In particular, there is the "Basic Venn." Since Highcharts does not have any Venn charts available yet (without tweaking and repurposing other chart types), I figured a good workaround might be to access the Office libraries from an MVC controller and dynamically create it that way, sending a rendered image to the View by ActionResult.

I looked in these resources for "SmartArt" without any luck.

- [.NET (version 4.5) Framework Class Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Nuget EPPlus classes I have installed in my project, especially the OfficeOpenXml classes

Is there a namespace that I can include so that I can dynamically create and return a SmartArt Basic Venn Diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Word on a server is not a supported scenario. Have you looked at client side solutions in javascript? I'm sure you can make something with [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) and someone has already made a library on top of D3.js to create [Venn diagrams](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/).

Comment: This is a very good tool, also available via Nuget. I verified that I can create the chart both using static text in the scripts section and also dynamically reading from a JsonResult with $.ajax().